# issue establishing connection to localhost database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am learning PHP and trying to establish a connection with my database so i can do simple data input/output. I am learning object oriented PHP. I have an index.php which calls the database.php file. The database.php file has all the connection material. The database has been created on my localhost. I am trying to connect to it. Using the PDO .

**The code in the database.php file is :**

```
<?php 

class Database{

    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $dbname = 'edunoix';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct(){
        //dsn or connection string
        $dsn = 'myql:host='. $this->$host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        //set pdo options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT =>true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        //create a new pdo
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }catch(PDOEception $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**When i compile and run i get the following error:**

```
   ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: host in C:\wamp\www\oophp\pdo\classes\Database.php on line 16
    Call Stack
    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
    1   0.0005  237960  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
    2   0.0010  247584  Database->__construct( )    ..\index.php:5


( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\wamp\www\oophp\pdo\classes\Database.php on line 16
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  237960  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0010  247584  Database->__construct( )    ..\index.php:5
```

Please tell me how can i resolve this. I am new and following an online tutorial so please help me correct the issue. Any help will be appriciated

Comment: just wondering *$this->pass* this should be *$this->password*, right?

Comment: just changed it still the issue on line 16 does not get resolved

Comment: line 16 is this code **$this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);** right?

Comment: line 16 is 
$dsn = 'myql:host='. $this->$host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

Comment: it might have something to do with $host . since am using a localhost i just wrote localhost. Is that correct or something else needs to be done?

Comment: yes, try making it public all of your variables.

Comment: it seems the issue is your variable is not define. not yet the issue whether the value is correct or not.

Comment: just did and that did not resolve anything

Comment: can you show your code which calls the Database class?

Comment: <?php 

require 'classes/Database.php';

$database = new Database;

 ?>

Comment: please help cause being new all this is too overwhelming and heartbreaking :(

Comment: a typo `$this->$host`

Comment: where is the typo i dont get it?

Comment: ok got that error resolved

Comment: now i got another error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\wamp\www\oophp\pdo\classes\Database.php

Comment: PDOException: could not find driver in C:\wamp\www\oophp\pdo\classes\Database.php on line 24

Comment: Line 24 is: $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->password, $options);

Comment: change `myql:` to `mysql:`

Comment: thank you sir
you are all awesome :)

Comment: You guys made my day :)

Answer (score -2):

use this code: if you want to upgrade your PDO class.BaseDao{

```
protected $user="root";
protected $pass="";
protected $name="mydatabase";
protected $dbh=null;

    function openConn(){
        $this->dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$this->name,$this->user,$this->pass);

        }
     function closeConn(){
 $this->dbh=null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change and why?